# Emacs hide/show support for C++ triple-slash Doxygen markup?

Tags: c++, emacs, doxygen

I use Doxygen's triple-slash syntax to markup my C++ code.  There are
two important cases which arise:

1) block markup comments which are the sole element on the line and may
   or may not begin flush left; e.g.

```
class foo
/// A one sentence brief description of foo.  The elaboration can
/// continue on for many lines.
{
    ...
};

void foo::bar
    /// A one sentence brief description of bar.  The elaboration can
    /// continue on for many lines.
    () const
{
    ...
}
```

2) trailing markup comments which always follow some number of C++
   tokens earlier on the first line but may still spill over onto
   subsequent lines; e.g.

```
class foo
{
    int  _var1;                 ///< A brief description of _var1.
    int  _var2;                 ///< A brief description of _var2
                                ///< requiring additional lines.
}

void foo::bar
    ( int arg1                  ///< A brief description of arg1.
    , int arg2                  ///< A brief description of arg2
                                ///< requiring additional lines.
    ) const
{
    ...
}
```

I wonder what hide/show support exists to deal with these conventions.
The most important cases are the block markup comments.  Ideally I would
like to be able to eliminate these altogether, meaning that I would
prefer not to waste a line simply to indicate presence of a folded
block markup comment, preferring a fringe marker, a la [hideshowvis.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/hideshowvis.el).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, as a partial answer the following snippet of code would do the trick.
Press M-s M-s in C++-mode and it hides all comments of the kind you described. Again pressing M-s M-s reveals the comments again. I know that the short code has its limitations:

1. It would be nice if one could hide/show each special comment separately.
2. Since all special comments are hidden you would need M-s M-s quite often. Therefore, `hs1-mode` should be more effective on large C++-files (maybe, it should be implmented via `jit-font-lock`).
3. Consecutive lines of special comments should be joined to one hidden block.

---

```
(defvar hs1-regexp
  "\\(\n[[:blank:]]*///\\|///<\\).*$"
  "List of regular expressions of blocks to be hidden.")

(define-minor-mode hs1-mode
  "Hide/show predefined blocks."
  :lighter " hs1"
  (if hs1-mode
      (let (ol)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward-regexp hs1-regexp nil 'noErr)
        (when (eq (syntax-ppss-context (syntax-ppss (match-end 1))) 'comment)
          (setq ol (make-overlay (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))
          (overlay-put ol 'hs1 t)
          (overlay-put ol 'invisible t)
          ))))
    (remove-overlays (point-min) (point-max) 'hs1 t)
    ))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook '(lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "M-s M-s") 'hs1-mode)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This achieves exactly what I wanted.

Comment: For some reason nothing happens when I press Alt+s (either once or twice), but I can switch to the mode by doing Alt+x hs1-mode.