# Hiding all doxygen comments in the active Emacs buffer

Tags: c++, emacs, doxygen

Is there a way to hide all doxygen comments in the active Emacs buffer?
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2936111/2725810) question asks only about single-line comments.
There is also the [Hide Or Ignore Comments](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideOrIgnoreComments) package, but that hides all comments, including non-doxygen ones.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't believe such a package exists. You'll have to hide them each manually with something like [HideShow](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideShow) or hide all comments with the package you mentioned.

A better question might be: why are doxygen comments less valuable than non-doxygen comments? You'd figure the intentional, structured doxygen comments would be more useful than a haphazard scattering of non-doxygen comments.

Comment: Doxygen comments take a lot of space and make interfaces scattered. This may be inconvenient if you want to look things up in the middle of implementing something without going to your browser. In this case, you do not want to hide all comments, since you want to see the comments for local variables, loops etc.